# Edit/update rails has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My first question in Stackoverflow.
I've been learning Rails for a week. I have a project with this structure:

```
class Community < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :community_neighbors
  has_many :community_coordinators 
  has_one :work_table 
end
```

This view (just for the new):

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @community, @community.community_neighbors.build ]) do |f| %>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :Nombre %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name%>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :Apellido %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :Teléfono %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :"E-mail" %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :mail %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and this controller

```
class CommunityNeighborsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
  end

  def edit
    @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
    @community_neighbor = @community.community_neighbors.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
    @community_neighbors = @community.community_neighbors.create(community_neighbors_params)
    redirect_to community_path(@community)
  end

  def update
    @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
    @community_neighbor = @community.community_neighbors.find(params[:id])
    @community_neighbor.update_attributes(community_neighbor_params)
  end


  private
    def community_neighbors_params
  params.require(:community_neighbor).permit(:name, :surname, :phone, :mail, :status)
    end
  end
```

I have an edit form for Community father's class that works perfectly with the autofill in the edit's form.

Problem: When I edit the child class community_neighbor, the autofill is not working.

Don't know if i need to post something else

I really appreciate your help!

Edit: This is like the [First Raill app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), but i need to make an edit view/controller for 'comments'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues in your code:

- You are not updating anything in the update method. You should use `update_attributes`.
- You are searching the community using the id instead of the community_id.
- You are using `@community.Community_neighbors` (caps).

Fixed update method:

```
def update
  @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
  @community_neighbor = @community.community_neighbors.find(params[:id])
  @community_neighbor.update_attributes(community_neighbor_params)
end
```

**EDIT: More issues**

I found another issue. In edit, you are looking for a specific Community Neighbor. But in the view you are not showing this Neighbor but a new (empty) one. You should change it this way:

```
def new
  @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
  @community_neighbor = @community.new
end

def edit
  @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
  @community_neighbor = @community.community_neighbors.find(params[:id])
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @community, @community_neighbor ]) do |f| %>
 ....
<%= end %>
```

Comment: I made ur fixes, thanks. But my problem is the view, this line 
    `<%= form_with(model: [ @community, 
    @community.community_coordinators.build ]) do |f| %>` I think is just for creating a new community_coordinator. I need to make an new and edit form

Comment: You are adding a community coordinator in the form, but you are showing the community neighbor controller.

Comment: Lol u'r right. But is practically the same, just change the neighboor/coordinator name

Comment: I edited my answer. In the view you are always showing an empty neighbor, not the one already created.

Comment: You can also accept and upvote the answer - that's the best way to show your appreciation :). This way the question is no longer unanswered and other people will know this worked for you, without having to read comments. Thank you!